# Format table issue converting markdown to pdf with jupyter notebook

Tags: macos, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I have the markdown code below for a table in a jupyter notebook.  If I render the notebook to html the formatting comes out fine.  If I try to render it to pdf, the formatting comes out terrible, jumbled up no borders.  I'm working on a mac, any tips on how to solve this.  My end goal is to get a pdf version.

Code:

```
| user_id |  business_id |
| :------------: | :-----------------: |    
| CxDOIDnH8gp9KXzpBHJYXw |  650 |   
| bLbSNkLggFnqwNNzzq-Ijw |  233 |   
| ELcQDlf69kb-ihJfxZyL0A |  176 |   
| d_TBs6J3twMy9GChqUEXkg |  166 |   
| Wu0yySWcHQ5tZ_59HNiamg |  163 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Got one solution, open the html in safari and then export to pdf.